# Replacing every occurrence of a word in C

Tags: c, string, replace

So, I have to replace every occurrence of a word in a larger string and I have a function to do so which looks like this:

```
void replace(char *sir, char *word1, char *word2) {
    char *buffer;
    buffer = calloc(LMAX, sizeof(char));
    char *insert_point = &buffer[0];
    char *tmp = sir;
    int l1 = strlen(word1);
    int l2 = strlen(word2);
    while (1) {
        char *p = strstr(tmp, word1);
        if (p == NULL) {
            strcpy( insert_point, tmp );
            break;
        }
        memcpy(insert_point, tmp, p - tmp);
        insert_point += p - tmp;
        memcpy(insert_point, word2, l2);
        insert_point += l2;
        tmp = p + l1;
    }
    strcpy(sir, buffer);
    free(buffer);
}
```

Which works, but it replaces substrings as well, not only the words. By example, if I have: "This is my string ing" and I want to replace 'ing' with 'watermelon' I'll get something like this: "This is my strwatermelon watermelon".
So, my question would be how can I make my program to check if what's he's replacing is a word or not?

Comment: Check whether the characters right before and right after the string are letters. Make sure to not check before the 1st char though.

Comment: You are making wild assumptions about buffer sizes.  What guarantee do you have that the resulting string will be at most `LMAX-1` bytes long and will fit in the source buffer pointed to by `sir`?

Comment: I'm gonna realloc right after I get the function to work properly

Comment: You need to tell us how you wish to define a "word". Is that something surrounded by spaces? By non-letters? Are digits parts of words, or do they separate them? Likewise for _...

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if there's a whitespace before and after the word you are going to replace. With special conditions:

- For first word, previous word doesn't exist.
- For last word, next word doesn't exist.

I have added the logic for this in your code:

```
void replace(char *sir, char *word1, char *word2)
{
    char *buffer;
    buffer = calloc( 100, sizeof(char) );
    char *insert_point = &buffer[0];
    char *tmp = sir;
    int l1 = strlen( word1 );
    int l2 = strlen( word2 );
    while(1)
    {
            char *p = strstr( tmp, word1 );
            if( p == NULL )
            {
                    strcpy( insert_point, tmp );
                    break;
            }
            memcpy( insert_point, tmp, p-tmp );
            insert_point += p-tmp;

            if ( (p == sir || isspace((unsigned char)p[-1])) && 
                 (isspace((unsigned char)p[l1]) || p[l1] == 0) ) {
                   memcpy( insert_point, word2, l2 );
                   insert_point += l2;
                }
                else { 
                   memcpy(insert_point, word1, l1);
                   insert_point += l1;
                }
                tmp = p+l1;
        }
        strcpy( sir, buffer );
        free( buffer );
    }
```

Comment: The `char` argument to `isspace` must be converted to `unsigned char`:  `isspace((unsigned char)p[l1])`.  Otherwise negative `char` values invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: You can simplify the word boundary test from 6 comparisons down to just 4 comparisons: `if ((p == sir || isspace((unsigned char)p[-1])) && (isspace((unsigned char)p[l1]) || p[l1] == '\0'))`.  The current implementation fails to match the searched word if it is alone on the line.

Comment: @chqrlie I often forget *that* cast :) Thanks for the suggestion. I have included it the answer.